# "which app" vs. "sudo which app"

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo

i'm using ubuntu 18.04 and i just installed an app using make install

the app is now installed in /usr/local/my_app/bin/my_app

when i run `which my_app`
i get this:
`/usr/local/my_app/bin/my_app`

but when i run `sudo which my_app` i get nothing.

i tried

`sudo chown root /usr/local/my_app` but it didn't work.

i need to run this app using a script that must be run as root.

how can i get root to see it?

Edit:

when i run the script as root, the script checks for the app using `shutil.which('my_app')` and it doesn't find it and terminates.

Edit:

adding `/usr/local/my_app/bin` to `/etc/sudoers` and `~/.bashrc` fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried running your script with `sudo` and see if it works or not?

Comment: Try `sudo -E ...` to keep _your_ PATH.